# JDBC Sybase Connectivity is not working?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, database-connection, sybase

I have used jconn3.jar for connecting the java application to SYBASE DB.

It shows "Login failed JZ00L" error.

Search through this error it shows some charset issue but not sure about the root cause of this problem

Then i able to download version3 jar alone from java2s where i can get the other versions??

Please help me to out come of this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://www.kangarooit.com/developer_blog/2006/11/sybase-error-jz00l-when-trying-to.php

Comment: Sometimes a problem is not a problem if you just don't make a problem out of it. "Login failed" seems pretty clear to me; you expect user credentials to work, but they don't. The account configuration needs to be checked. Annoying, but you must do it or get a DBA to do it for you.

Comment: No the same credentials is working when i got connected through Aqua editor.I am sure the problem is not with credentials.

Comment: Sybase does not agree with you. Unless you are making the not so uncommon mistake of connecting to the wrong database.